# Can i post a solution to a problem in math.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2984486/dashboard#s=p2 There is a problem in last year's codejam, it asks to decide given shuffled numbers comes from which randomizing algorithms. Absolute solution is very hard to find and it is not known yet. But i found it. Can i post it on math.stackexhange ? it will not be a question but an answer, is it allowed ? Or maybe should i post on cs. stackexhange? Thanks in advance

I asked, didnt i? i asked ! read again, i asked a question in meta forum and added tag discussion. What are these downvotes ? Should i ask only things you like ? Look up dictionary and learn the meaning of discussion, people like you make here a worse place

Comment: What's the endgame? You just want to post your solution? Is it mathematical, or is it an algorithm with or without an implementation?

Comment: Yes i want to post my solution for people who searches internet later, now people ask on different sites but i like stackexchange. I will never post something especially on quara, and other many unknown sites. It is definitely mathematical of course, the absolute probabilitiesfor strange randomizing algorithm. but i now i think of it, computer science may be better. It is more puzzly

Comment: math.stackexchange is not intended to be a site for publishing solutions to outstanding problems, end of discussion. Start of different discussion: I am not very familiar with codejam. Are they in the habit of posing unsolved problems? Do they approve of people posting solutions of their problems to sites like math.stackexchange?

Comment: Why the down-votes. The question is a perfectly good one about what MSE is for.

Comment: @RobArthan, [A downvote on a meta question primarily means "no"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/718/5531), not "this is not appropriate for meta".

Comment: I upvoted your question, interesting idea, so let's discuss as you intended to do :). I have some questions for you to start the discussion: (a) do you want to post this such that people can find back it later on, (b) do you maybe want to add this because you are proud on what you have done and want to show it and get some motivational feedback from the community or maybe something entirely different. Basically what is the basic reason for posting this and what might also play a more minor role. Then I better understand in which direction you are thinking. ;)

Comment: I am still not pro or contra, I first want to understand in which direction you are thinking, and then I can start asking side questions and post what I think might be positive and what I think might be concerns. But before that, I need to be sure that I am thinking in entirely the same direction as you are and understand what you want to do correctly. ;) –  Pedro 14 hours ago

Answer (score 4):

If you are uncertain about whether your solution to a mathematical problem is correct, than that is a good question to ask in MSE. If you want to publish a solution to a known problem, then MSE is not the right forum.